# Cordova - How to upload image file from gallery to java server?

Tags: javascript, java, php, android, cordova

I am following [this example](http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/07/12/upload-image-using-file-transfer-cordova-plugin-for-ios-and-android/), it is working fine but i want to upload file through Spring Java Server not using PHP Server.

These codes are the example of one which I make.

[upload.js]

```js
function uploadPhoto(imageNme) {
 var imageURI = $('#imageFrame').attr('src');
 var imageNme = imageNme;
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageNme;
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
    options.headers = {
     Connection: "close"
    };
    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "value1";
    params.value2 = "value2";

    options.params = params;

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    fileTransfer.upload(
  imageURI, 
  "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/upload.php", 
  win, 
  fail, 
  options
 );
}
```

[upload.php]

```js
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$new_image_name = iconv("UTF-8","EUC-KR",$_FILES['file']['name']); 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "C:/Users/MyPC/Desktop/img/".$new_image_name);
?>
```

If it is like this, the file is well saved on the path where I choose.
However, I use Spring Java Server and the file upload would like to be realized.

I am looking for [one example](http://jnylove.tistory.com/385) using Java Server. But this example is not perfect. So I can't use this. How can i use Filetransfer in cordova?

Comment: Please remove those run code snippet buttons and so. They are useless.